# Better way to store html content in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Is there a way to store tag in DB without using HTML tags. In order words I dont want the string thats getting stored to be like
`'<b>This</b> is a sample'`, instead it could be some kind of encoded format.
As of now I have a got a few findings like encoding the html content before storing it via some 3rd party library

### https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he

However, is there any better approach to do the same without using 3rd party library?

Comment: `Is there a way to store tag in DB without using HTML tags.` What exactly does that mean? How exactly do you want the result to look?

Comment: I mean like I dont want string like `'<b>This</b> is a sample'` to get stored in database

Comment: So what _do_ you want to store in your DB instead?

Comment: any kind of encoded so some format using escapes, that also supports newline etc

Comment: `any kind of` What? If you don't know the encoding you want to store, _why_ do you want to encode it in the first place?

Comment: Actually I used the term encoding becoz that would contain the formattings like space, tab etc which I would need during fetch -> decode and then rendering it on UI

Comment: Imagine I want to store comments from a text editor,

Comment: I still don't understand why you don't store the original string if you need it like this on fetch anyway.

Comment: @tkausl My guess is OP don't want to store original content due to security concerns, you know XSS, CSRF, etc.  The short answer is "no", there is nothing built-in. Mongo is just a database - it stores data. Sanitise it on app level. Many would even recommend to do not tamper with user's input - save it as is and escape the output instead. It has many advantages and I might even advocate for that if escaping wasn't so expensive.

Comment: @AlexBlex Neither of these security concerns has anything to do with the database however. And since OP mentioned __de__coding it again when reading from the database, it seems pointless.